# MDX : filter parents with children

Tags: mdx, mondrian

I've got the following query :

```
SELECT 
NON EMPTY { [Measures].[Mes] } ON COLUMNS,
NON EMPTY { [Dim].[Lev1].Members, [Dim].[Lev2].Members } ON ROWS 
FROM [Cube]
```

Where Lev2 is the hierarchical child of Lev1.
That gives me the following result :

```
Lev1 | Lev2 | Mes
_________________
yes  | 1    | 1
yes  | 2    | 2
no   | 3    | 3
no   | 4    | 4
```

EDIT : Maybe this view is more relevant :

```
Dim      | Mes
- yes    | 3
      1  | 1
      2  | 2
- no     | 7
      3  | 3
      4  | 4
```

What I want is to filter Lev1 with Lev2 = 2 or Lev2 = 4 to get the following result :

```
Lev1 | Mes
___________
yes  |  2
no   |  4
```

Is this is even possible?

I'm using Mondran and Olap4j.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just discover the VisualTotals function which does the job well:

```
SELECT
NON EMPTY {[Measures].[Mt cheques]} ON COLUMNS,
NON EMPTY VisualTotals (hierarchize({
    [Dim].[Lev1].Members, 
    [Dim].[yes].[2], 
    [Dim].[no].[4]
)}) ON ROWS
FROM [Cube]
```

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

It seems that `Lev1` and `Lev2` are attribute hierarchies. As these can be separate (like making up two columns of your row header of your first query), you also can split them between the row and the where axis:

```
SELECT 
NON EMPTY { [Measures].[Mes] } ON COLUMNS,
NON EMPTY { [Dim].[Lev1].Members } ON ROWS 
FROM [Cube]
WHERE { [Dim].[Lev2].[2], [Dim].[Lev2].[4] }
```

Comment: Lev1 and Lev2 are respectively parent and child of a same hierarchy in Dim dimension. So they can't be separated on two differents axes. So I tried using an aggregate and a "FakeDimension" but the result is wrong ([yes | 6] and [no | 6]). But maybe it's a mondrian's bug?

Comment: @pDupond I do not know Mondrian in detail. But in Analysis Services, if `Lev1` and `Lev2` are two levels of the same hierarchy, then you cannot even get them back as two separate columns in the row headers, but only as one column with members of both levels mixed. Do you have the attribute hierarchies from the columns on which these levels are based available in your cube?

Comment: I apologize for the poor quality of my explanations. I edited my question. I hope it will be more relevant.

Comment: @FrankPl +1 after the OP edit I'm not sure how to achieve this - is the `subselect` in my answer a valid approach? (seems over complicated)

Answer (score 0):

I think this is effectively the same as FrankPI's answer. Although this may work in your application:

```
SELECT 
NON EMPTY 
 { [Measures].[Mes] } 
ON COLUMNS,
NON EMPTY 
 EXISTS(
    { [Dim].[Lev1].Members }
    , { [Dim].[Lev2].[2], [Dim].[Lev2].[4] }
 ) 
ON ROWS 
FROM [Cube]
```

Maybe a `subselect`

```
SELECT 
NON EMPTY 
 { [Measures].[Mes] } 
ON COLUMNS,
NON EMPTY 
 EXISTS(
    { [Dim].[Lev1].Members }
    , { [Dim].[Lev2].[2], [Dim].[Lev2].[4] }
 ) 
ON ROWS 
FROM 
(
  SELECT { [Dim].[Lev2].[2], [Dim].[Lev2].[4] } ON 0
  FROM   [Cube]
)
```

Comment: I tried and this gave me the following result : [yes | 3] [no | 7]. Thank you anyway.

Comment: @pDupond - I added another attempt using a `subselect` - not sure if your client will be too happy with this.

Comment: Unfortunately, Mondrian doesn't support sub-select queries, so I am not able to try your solution.